# Liferay portal with "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Tags: browser, liferay, friendly-url, redirect-loop

I have the portal http://fut5.co configured with Liferay 6.1. However, there is a problem when viewing from the Web browser. The first time I visit the site everything works fine, but when I try to visit again, the next message appears:

"This webpage has a redirect loop"

To reproduce this problem, each time I have to clear the browser's cache. This is impacting my visitors when returning to my site.

First time: fut5.co -> fut5.co/home
Second time: fut5.co -> Redirect loop

I configured the friendly url as: /portal
Public pages: fut5.co
Private pages: fut5

How can I fix this behavior? What do you think about that?

Comment: which browser you are referring?

Comment: I found that this is happening for Chrome-19, FF-12 & IE-9.

Comment: Yes, this is happening in Chrome 19, Firefox 10, Opera 11.64, Explorer 9 y Safare 5.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happening when you change the friendly URL for a site from "guest" to something else. A way to work around this, if you renamed to "something", is to go to `http://localhost:8080/web/something` instead of `http://localhost:8080/` - then the redirect loop will not happen. There might be an issue already filed for this (Edit: [LPS-27051](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-27051), fixed in 6.1 GA2). The quickest workaround is to not rename the default site.

Comment: I put it back to guest, and redirected loop disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I periodically run into this problem, Liferay gets corrupted.  I find the only solution is to completely re-install the Liferay instance.   I hope this doesn't happen once my application goes to a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the "Home URL" property on "Control Panel > Portal Settings > Navigation" to "/".

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check this property in portal-ext.properties? Right now, when you hit direct url, it is defaulting to /web/guest and thus it is redirecting.

> ```
> #
> # Specify the site name that will default to the company's virtual host.
> # If the specified site has a virtual host, then that will take precedence.
> # If it does not, then it will use the company's virtual host. This property
> # is useful to remove "/web/guest" (or any other site) from the default URL.
> # For example, if this property is not set, then the default URL may be
> # http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home. If this property is set, then the
> # default URL may be http://localhost:8080/home.
> #
> virtual.hosts.default.site.name=Guest
> ```